# How to properly import Wand to python?

Tags: python, import, path, importerror, wand

I am running into some issues when I try to import Wand (an ImageMagick binding for Python).

Here's what's happening:

```
from wand.image import Image
```

getting the standard error message:

```
ImportError: No module named wand.image
```

Yes, Wand is installed, I used

```
pip install Wand
```

From what I understand, it depends on imagemagick so I also needed to do this:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Still no luck. As far as I know, it should be able to import fine now, but it's not.

Other info: I am using homebrew on Mac and python 2.7 and I tried messing with virtual environments, but still couldn't get it to work. I have a hunch that I have something going wrong with my path, but I cannot figure out how to further troubleshoot this. I have uninstalled both imagemagick and wand and tried to reinstall them. I'm pretty inexperienced with python, any help is appreciated because I'm trying to learn! I read that I should check my sys.path, but when I print it I do not know what I'm checking for.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Please use [virtualenv](/questions/tagged/virtualenv), and re-do a pip install of wand inside an activated sandbox.

```sh
# Install virtualenv system-wide
sudo pip install virtualenv

# Create a python sandbox
virtualenv my_sandbox

# Activate sandbox session
. ./my_sandbox/bin/activate

# Install wand into sandbox environment
pip install wand

# Test installation
python -mwand.version
#=> 0.4.2
```

> How to properly import Wand to python?

You are correct in importing `wand.image.Image` with the following.

```py
from wand.image import Image
# ...
with Image(filename='rose:') as img:
  pass
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting the error: TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be string, not unicode

Comment: @m2pathan See [this fix](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/issues/326). Recent version of python/windows dropped auto-casting on ctypes, so you'll need to patch the api to enforce `str(libmagick_path)`.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue and found out it was a bad idea to name my file `wand.py`